# CORS Cross-origin resource sharing And Json Web Token

Tags: security, https, http-headers, cors, jwt

In my application I have included a page from a different server/domain. For simplicity I will refer to my main application **Web A**, and the other **Web B**.

Somewhere i **A**, after the user has logged in, I will load a page from **B** by using CORS and jwt. 
In **A** I create an encoded token that I pass to Ajax. Ajax adds this token inside the Header( **"Authorization"** = *bearer + encoded token*).

**B** then uses this token to decode and grab usersId and group it belongs to, and determine whether or not user has access to the resource. 
In addition there is also an **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** = *Web A* setup inside Web B, to only accept request from A.

My question is about the security part of CORS and the usage of jwt.
During development, when using Postman to access the resources in **B** directly, I could easiy bypass *"**Access-control-allow-origin**"*. 
And as long as I had the correct token, the resources were sent back with no problem! I mean all it takes is for some potential hacker to get hold of that encoded string, and they could easily use Postman to view the resources.

What is the next step here when it comes to the security part, because I'm completely lost!

Hope I explained the issue clearly. All help is highly appreciated

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I currently want to do something similar to you. I want to create a widget that a customer could use on their site. I only want customers who have created an account on my site to be able to use the api which returns the widget.

Answer (score 9):

CORS is not meant to protect you in the case of an attacker obtaining a user's JWT access token and requesting resources directly from Web B.

In actuality, CORS isn't a security feature at all, but instead a way to safely bypass a browser's same-origin policy, which is the security feature.  A same-origin policy (which essentially every browser implements) restricts a web page from accessing data on a web page from a different origin.

Imagine a situation where a browser didn't implement a same-origin policy.  Any webpage could request data from any origin, meaning that any malicious site could request data from banks, email accounts, or anywhere else. This browser would happily send along any HTTP cookies that were associated with those origins and all of those requests would be authorized. Attacks against this browser would be trivial.

So, it is clear that a same-origin policy is necessary for any browser.  However, as you have found out, it is often useful for websites to share data across origins.  This is why the CORS spec was created.  As long as both sides agree to share data cross origin, the browser will allow the request to be sent.

To answer your real question, the way to keep an attacker from using the JWT directly is to not allow them access to it in the first place.  You should protect the JWT as you would a HTTP session cookie or a password, because that is what it is.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and help Micheal Davis and @MattS.
Currently I use this bearer-token inside the Ajax, and so the encoded-token is visible in Dev-tools of the browser. 
Does protecting the JWT involde passing it to header elsewhere, and not inside the Ajax call? So that later on, by using HTTPS, make it even harder to get hold of the token?

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly right.  CORS exists to secure users in their web browser. Browsing or curling directly to site B is not protected by CORS.  A server may get any type of request from various clients and must secure itself.

Security of site B comes from using JWT properly (preferably over HTTPS).  First, the token is signed with a secret.  This lets you know others haven't altered it or created one themselves.  Second, the payload should include a relatively short expiration time.  The recipient of the token should ignore it after this time so a man-in-the-middle who gets a hold of the token has a very short time to use it.  And third, if you pass the token only through HTTPS then you have a very low chance anyone else will get it.